# Haskell convert string of char and int to a paired list

Tags: haskell

Hi guys I am looking for a function

```
expand :: String -> [(Char,Int)]
```

that takes a string of character and numbers like `"a5b3c2"` and change it to a paired list of the string like `"[('a',5),('b',3),('c',2)]"` in that same form.

Example:

```
expand "a5b4c2"
[('a',5),('b',4),('c',2)]

expand "d9d3"
[('d',9),('d',3)]
```

I had already made a function that does the opposite of the above, all I am trying to do is figure out how to do the inverse of that. Example:

```
flatten :: [(Char, Int)] -> String
flatten [] = []
flatten ((ca,cb):cs) = ca:(show cb ++ flatten cs)
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I had already defined a function that does the opposite of that: 

    flatten :: [(Char, Int)] -> String
    flatten [] = []
    flatten ((ca,cb):cs) = ca:(show cb ++ flatten cs)

I am trying to figure out how to do an inverse of it to create "expand"

Comment: Something close: `import Data.List.Split` -- `import Data.List` --  `mystring = "a5b2c3"` -- `map (\[x,y] -> (x,y)) $ splitPlaces (replicate (length x `div` 2) 2) $ wordsBy (==',') $ intersperse ',' mystring` --
**[("a","5"),("b","2"),("c","3")]**

Comment: Please update your question with the information you put in the comment. Many people don't read comments.

Comment: Can `"a123b456c8d9"` be valid input as well?

Answer (score 2):

Is it ok like this?

```
import Data.List (intersperse)
import Data.List.Split (splitPlaces, wordsBy)
mystring = "a5b2c3'

>>> map (\[x,y] -> (head x, read y :: Int)) $ splitPlaces (replicate (length mystring `div` 2) 2) $ wordsBy (==',') $ intersperse ',' mystring
[('a',5),('b',2),('c',3)]
```

Simpler, thanks to @4castle:

```
import Data.List (intersperse)
import Data.List.Split (chunksOf, wordsBy)
map (\[x,y] -> (head x, read y :: Int)) $ chunksOf 2 $ wordsBy (==',') $ intersperse ',' mystring
```

Even simpler, still thanks to @4castle:

```
import Data.List.Split (chunksOf)
map (\[x,y] -> (x, read [y] :: Int)) $ chunksOf 2 mystring
```

Comment: `splitEvery 2` would be shorter

Comment: @4castle I didn't know. Let me look and I edit. Feel free to edit too if you're sure of you.

Comment: @4castle `splitEvery` is deprecated, I put `chunksOf` instead

Comment: The `intersperse` and `wordsBy` are also unnecessary. `map (\[x,y] -> (x, read [y] :: Int)) $ chunksOf 2 mystring`

Comment: You're right  once again @4castle. I edit. I often do more complicated as needed >-<

Comment: Your last solution is definitely the easiest one. Written in list comprehension it might even look easier.

Comment: @Elmex80s The credit to the last solution is highly shared with 4castle. If you have a simpler solution, feel free to post it or to edit my post.

Answer (score 2):

Use a parsing library like `Parsec`. The learning curve is a little steep (I'm not even sure this is a good example), but you can describe parsers like this is very little code.

```
import qualified Text.Parsec as T

parseDigit :: T.Parsec String () Int
parseDigit = fmap (read . pure) T.digit

myParser = T.many ((,) <$> T.letter <*> parseDigit)
```

Then

```
> T.parse myParser "" "a5b4c2"
Right [('a', 5),('b',4),('c',2)]
```

So, your `expand` could be defined as

```
import Data.Either
expand :: String -> [(Char, Int)]
expand s = fromRight [] (T.parse myParser "" s)
```

to return an empty list in the event the parser fails on the input string.

Answer (score 0):

Without any complicated imports, assuming alternating chars and (single) digits, you can use a simple recursion:

```
f :: [(Char, Int)] -> String
f (c:d:xs) = (c,read [d]):f xs
f x        = x
```

Answer (score 0):

A relatively simple solution:

```
import Data.Char (digitToInt)

expand :: String -> [(Char, Int)]
expand (x:x':xs) = (x, digitToInt x'):expand xs
expand _        = []
```

Answer (score 0):

Again, I prefer list comprehensions and/or tail recursion functions. If a function is not a fold then it returns a list. List comprehensions return lists.

```
let l = "a5b3c2"
[ (a,(read [b] :: Int)) | (a,b) <- zip l (tail l), elem b "1234567890"]
```

[('a',5),('b',3),('c',2)]

I didn't know about the `chunksOf` function when I posted this. `chunksOf` is a very handy function and I'm already using it a lot. Also I think I like the `ord` function over the `read` function. When you have pairs, you know where things are at and can process accordingly.

```
[ (a,(ord b)-48) | (a:b:c) <- chunksOf 2 "a5b4c3"]
```